# making a back-up with mysql database and codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, download, database-backups

i want to back-up my mysql database in my site. I am making a button to be pressed, and after it was onlick , it fires my back-up database function thru ajax and i want to download the .zip of my database file

now here is my code, why it is the .zip file was not appearing. It says in my ajax that it is success. with a reply of

[image]

here is my code in javascript:

```
function auto_backup() {
  $.ajax({
    url: siteurl+"admin_backup/backup_db",
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
      alert("Success");
    }
  });
}
```

and my controller code:

```
public function backup_db() {
        $this->load->dbutil();

        $prefs = array(     
                'format'      => 'zip',             
                'filename'    => 'my_db_backup.sql'
              );
        $backup =& $this->dbutil->backup($prefs); 

        $db_name = 'backup-on-'. date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") .'.zip';
        $save = 'pathtobkfolder/'.$db_name;

        $this->load->helper('file');
        write_file($save, $backup); 

        $this->load->helper('download');
        force_download($db_name, $backup); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without ajax it should work, as far as i know download with ajax dosen't work.

```
function auto_backup() {
  window.location.href = siteurl+"admin_backup/backup_db";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give direct link to your button as follows. No need to use AJAX

```
 href="<?php echo site_url("admin_backup/backup_db") ?>"
```